# How can we fill a column with specific values in Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have a table in kusto with 13,000 rows. I would like to know how can I create a new column in this table which **fill it** with only 2 values (0 and 1) randomly. Is there also a possibility to create a column containing 3 different value of data type: string ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can extend a calculated column using the `rand()` function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/randfunction

for example:

1. `0` or `1`:

   ```
   | extend y = toint(rand(1) > 0.5)
   ```
2. 1 of 3 strings (`first`, `second` or `third`):

   ```
   | extend r = rand(3)
   | extend s = case(r <= 0, "first", r <= 1, "second", "third")
   | project-away r
   ```

if you need to do this at ingestion time, you can use an update policy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy

or if you want to do this for the existing table, you can use a `.set-or-replace` command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query